# no unique field / key for table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with mysql database. I have a table of Person and I want one unique field for it to be a primary key so that one may search for a specific person in the db table, now consider this person table contains data of lost people in any disaster situation and we cannot select cnic or name as a primary key because in such situations cnic is impossible to search and name cannot be unique. Also later this table will be updated (if that person is found) and deleted too. Now my question is that, what to do with this situation, what should i do to handle this.

Comment: You can do something that everyone is doing: use integer unique ID.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Comment: Why do you need a key to search for persons in the database? Why can't you search by name, for example?

Comment: Just use auto_increment like @ElonThan suggested. There's no reason to   worry yourself with this topic, those auto_incremented integers play an important role in the performance of the write speed as well.

Comment: @jpesout http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0986263/